# Can Covid-19 (similarly to HIV) infect T-Cells?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, hiv

I'm interested in better understanding [this Nature publication](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41423-020-0424-9), discussing the potential for Covid to infect t-cells.

After describing the results they conclude:

"**Based on the results of pseudovirus and live virus infection, here we proved that (1) SARS-CoV-2 could infect T cells**, (2) SARS-CoV-2 infected T cells through receptor-dependent, S protein-mediated membrane fusion, and (3) infection could be inhibited by EK1 peptide."

Is this big news? I am not an expert but I believe that HIV's special trait is it's ability to infect CD4+ T cells. If this virus has this ability, does it mean it will have long-term effects like [lymphocytopenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphocytopenia), which occurs in HIV?

Comment: Cell-cell fusion means it can probably infect and even replicate inside any kind of cell? But this is probably a minor target compared to type II cells. In the paper they obtained significant virus entry and cell-cell fusion but not significant replication inside their T-cell line. It might explain partially some of the pathogenic effect in particular if the virus induces apoptosis or just cytokine release in immunity cells.

Answer (score 6):

As referenced the publication you shared, [other human corona viruses](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hin_Chu2/publication/281852899_Middle_East_Respiratory_Syndrome_Coronavirus_Efficiently_Infects_Human_Primary_T_Lymphocytes_and_Activates_the_Extrinsic_and_Intrinsic_Apoptosis_Pathways/links/5606b98908aeb5718ff679e3/Middle-East-Respiratory-Syndrome-Coronavirus-Efficiently-Infects-Human-Primary-T-Lymphocytes-and-Activates-the-Extrinsic-and-Intrinsic-Apoptosis-Pathways.pdf) also infect, but do not replicate in T cells, so it's not "Big News" in the sense of being a novel or unexpected finding. This also differs from HIV, which actively [replicates in CD4+ T Cells](https://www.avert.org/about-hiv-aids/how-infects-body). However, it does seem like CoV-2 patients have [reduced T-cells after recovery](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41423-020-0402-2), and that reduced lymphocyte levels during infection [are associated with greater risk of mortality](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.03.08.20031229v2) from COVID-19.

It doesn't seem like there's any evidence in the literature for long-term lymphocytopenia in recovered SARS and MERS patients, but it's still too early make any strong conclusions about long-term effects from the current outbreak.

Comment: So, the T-Cell is susceptible, but not permissive?

Comment: Now 20 months later are there any newer results?