# T-cell "exhaustion" in patients with Covid-19

Tags: immunology, coronavirus, hiv

Following up on [my previously asked question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92548/can-covid-19-similarly-to-hiv-infect-t-cells), which asks how COVID infects T-cells in immune system.

Here's a study that shows that recovered covid patients have "exausted t-cells". To quote:

> T cell counts are reduced significantly in COVID-19 patients, and the
>   surviving T cells appear functionally exhausted. Non-ICU patients,
>   with total T cells, CD8+T cells CD4+T cells counts lower than 800/μL,
>   300/μL, and 400/μL, respectively, may still require aggressive
>   intervention even in the immediate absence of more severe symptoms due
>   to a high risk for further deterioration in condition.

Is this normal for other coronaviruses (like the common cold)? Also is it possible that this immune damage can be a long-term effect, similar to HIV?

Comment: It's not a flu-like virus! Symptoms may be similar, since they are not specific, though flu doesn't cause interstitial inflammations and pulmonary embolism!

Comment: I edited this so that it's more clear. In a previous question people said that it's normal for coronaviruses to infect T-cells. By "flu-like" I was referring to other coronaviruses like the common cold that spread through airborn droplets like the flu.